Checkbox state does not change
`I am using vue3 with options api`
For the code posted below, I have a checkbox that when checked, the method onCheckboxGeoTIFFOverlayBandAveragesChanged() should be executed. Despite I check and uncheck the the checkbox several times, the log statement in onCheckboxGeoTIFFOverlayBandAveragesChanged
always displays that the valus of isCheckboxGeoTIFFOverlayBandAveragesChecked is false.
please let me know why that is happening and how to solve it
code:
<template>
    <cds-checkbox id="idCheckboxGeoTIFFOverlayBandAveragesContainer">
        <label id="idTextGeoTIFFOverlayBandAverages">{{ tempTextBandAverages }}</label>
        <input
            type="checkbox"
            :value="compPropsVModelCheckGeoTIFFOverlayBandAverages"
            @input="$emit('update:compPropsVModelCheckGeoTIFFOverlayBandAverages', $event.target.checked)"
            :disabled="isCheckboxGeoTIFFOverlayBandAveragesDisabled"
            :checked="isCheckboxGeoTIFFOverlayBandAveragesChecked"
            @change="onCheckboxGeoTIFFOverlayBandAveragesChanged"
        />
    </cds-checkbox>
</template>

<script>
import { GeoTIFFOverlaySettingsConstants } from '../../../resources/GeoTIFFOverlaySettings/GeoTIFFOverlaySettingsConstants.js';

let msg = null;

export default {
    name: 'SentinelHubGeoTIFFOverlayBand1',
    data() {
        return {
            tempTextBandAverages: GeoTIFFOverlaySettingsConstants.CONST_STRING_BAND_1_AVERAGES.description,
        };
    },
    components: {},
    props: {
        isCheckboxGeoTIFFOverlayBandAveragesChecked: {
            type: Boolean,
            default: false,
        },
        isCheckboxGeoTIFFOverlayBandAveragesDisabled: {
            type: Boolean,
            default: false,
        },
        vModelCheckGeoTIFFOverlayBandAverages: {
            type: Boolean,
            default: null,
        },
    },
    emits: {
        'update:vModelCheckGeoTIFFOverlayBandAverages': null,
    },
    computed: {
        compPropsVModelCheckGeoTIFFOverlayBandAverages: {
            get() {
                return this.vModelCheckGeoTIFFOverlayBandAverages;
            },
            set(value) {
                this.$emit('update:vModelCheckGeoTIFFOverlayBandAverages', value);
            },
        },
    },
    methods: {
        onCheckboxGeoTIFFOverlayBandAveragesChanged() {
            msg = JSON.stringify({msg:verboseTag + '@watch.', isChecked: this.isCheckboxGeoTIFFOverlayBandAveragesChecked});
            console.log(msg);
        },
    },
};
</script>


Your code can be more Vue.js idiomatic! Do you want the vModelCheckGeoTIFFOverlayBandAverages to be synced with the checkbox?
If so, I can re-write your component better. The result will be shocking. What is your exact Vue version?

@Raeisi yes I want it too synced.i am usin vue3 with options api.thanks

Binding and using Checkbox has always been a source of confusion. Simple and basic usage of Checkbox in Vue could be implemented like this:
<input
  type="checkbox"
  :value="vModelCheckGeoTIFFOverlayBandAverages"
  :disabled="isCheckboxGeoTIFFOverlayBandAveragesDisabled"
  @change="onCheckboxGeoTIFFOverlayBandAveragesChanged"
/>

onCheckboxGeoTIFFOverlayBandAveragesChanged(e) {
  console.log('is checked', e.target.checked); // true or false
},

The checkbox value prop is connected to the model value, and to observe changes we could listen to the change event and pick the current checked state from $event.target.checked. For other input types, the current state value is accessible from $event.target.value. The good implementation can be:
<template>
  <cds-checkbox id="idCheckboxGeoTIFFOverlayBandAveragesContainer">
    <label id="idTextGeoTIFFOverlayBandAverages">{{ tempTextBandAverages }}</label>
    <input
      type="checkbox"
      :value="vModelCheckGeoTIFFOverlayBandAverages"
      :disabled="isCheckboxGeoTIFFOverlayBandAveragesDisabled"
      @change="onCheckboxGeoTIFFOverlayBandAveragesChanged"
    />
  </cds-checkbox>
</template>

<script>
import { GeoTIFFOverlaySettingsConstants } from '../../../resources/GeoTIFFOverlaySettings/GeoTIFFOverlaySettingsConstants.js';

let msg = null;

export default {
  name: 'SentinelHubGeoTIFFOverlayBand1',
  data() {
    return {
      tempTextBandAverages: GeoTIFFOverlaySettingsConstants.CONST_STRING_BAND_1_AVERAGES.description,
    };
  },
  components: {},
  props: {
    // isCheckboxGeoTIFFOverlayBandAveragesChecked: {
    //   type: Boolean,
    //   default: false,
    // },
    isCheckboxGeoTIFFOverlayBandAveragesDisabled: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false,
    },
    vModelCheckGeoTIFFOverlayBandAverages: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: null,
    },
  },
  emits: {
    'update:vModelCheckGeoTIFFOverlayBandAverages': null,
  },
  computed: {
    // compPropsVModelCheckGeoTIFFOverlayBandAverages: {
    //   get() {
    //     return this.vModelCheckGeoTIFFOverlayBandAverages;
    //   },
    //   set(value) {
    //     this.$emit('update:vModelCheckGeoTIFFOverlayBandAverages', value);
    //   },
    // },
  },
  methods: {
    onCheckboxGeoTIFFOverlayBandAveragesChanged(e) {
      const val = e.target.checked;
      console.log('is checked', val);
      this.$emit('update:vModelCheckGeoTIFFOverlayBandAverages', val);

      msg = JSON.stringify({
        msg: verboseTag + '@watch.',
        isChecked: this.vModelCheckGeoTIFFOverlayBandAverages,
        // isChecked: this.isCheckboxGeoTIFFOverlayBandAveragesChecked,
      });
      console.log(msg);
    },
  },
};
</script>


The prop of isCheckboxGeoTIFFOverlayBandAveragesChecked does not make sense and there is no unique and defined usage.
The computed property of compPropsVModelCheckGeoTIFFOverlayBandAverages is no longer required.
The msg variable can be implemented as a computed property.
And the parent will get updated this way:
<SentinelHubGeoTIFFOverlayBand1 v-model:vModelCheckGeoTIFFOverlayBandAverages="checkBoxState"/>


A better and more idiomatic implementation could be like (Vue version ^3.4):
<template>
  <cds-checkbox id="idCheckboxGeoTIFFOverlayBandAveragesContainer">
    <label id="idTextGeoTIFFOverlayBandAverages">{{ tempTextBandAverages }}</label>
    <input
      type="checkbox"
      :disabled="isCheckboxGeoTIFFOverlayBandAveragesDisabled"
      v-model="model"
    />
  </cds-checkbox>
</template>

<script setup>
import { GeoTIFFOverlaySettingsConstants } from '../../../resources/GeoTIFFOverlaySettings/GeoTIFFOverlaySettingsConstants.js';

import { computed, ref } from 'vue';

const model = defineModel('vModelCheckGeoTIFFOverlayBandAverages', { default: null });

defineProps({
  isCheckboxGeoTIFFOverlayBandAveragesDisabled: {
    type: Boolean,
    default: false,
  },
});

const tempTextBandAverages = GeoTIFFOverlaySettingsConstants.CONST_STRING_BAND_1_AVERAGES.description;
// const tempTextBandAverages = ref(GeoTIFFOverlaySettingsConstants.CONST_STRING_BAND_1_AVERAGES.description);

const msg = computed(() => JSON.stringify({
  msg: verboseTag + '@watch.',
  isChecked: this.vModelCheckGeoTIFFOverlayBandAverages,
}));

</script>

FINALLY
As a suggestion, please use general names for your props. Say, to pass the disabled status, it is better to use the common name of disabled instead of isCheckboxGeoTIFFOverlayBandAveragesDisabled. Instead of vModelCheckGeoTIFFOverlayBandAverages use modelValue, which is the standard name of the primary model name in Vue 3.
